# How to push data to phoenix is chuncks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am very new to the this field. I am trying to push data from spark to phoenix. The size of the data is more than 1 million. The spark job runs fine with 100 thousand record but gets stuck when the number of records pass 1 million.
I am loading the data from hive

```
val hive_data = spark.sql(query)
```

Pushing it to phoenix

```
hive_data.write.format("org.apache.phoenix.spark").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).options(collection.immutable.Map(
          "zkUrl" -> zkUrl,
          "table" -> tableName)).save()
```

Does spark load the whole dataframe in memory before pushing it to phoenix?
Since it is able to process smaller number of records, the problem is to create batches to upload to phoenix. How do I create batches of dataframe?

Comment: If your original data table is not partitioned well, then the spark could try to load all data.

Comment: How to make sure that that the original data table is partitioned?

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution to the problem I was facing. Before pushing the dataframe to phoenix, spark was trying to load the whole dataframe in memory and was coming to a halt state. So the next option was to divide the dataframe and work with chunks.
Since the order did not matter in my case, I divided the dataframe into splits using randomSplit

```
val splitDF = hive_data.randomSplit(Array(1,1,1,1,1))
```

Then looped through each split and pushed the splitted dataframe to the phoenix table. This is taking a significant amount of time and hence further working on for an efficient solution. I'll update if found.